# How to integrate Conference Voice calls in Twilio Client for Android

Tags: android, twilio, voip

Till now I have followed the steps for [Twilio Client for Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/setup)  and successfully able to conduct client to client and client to PSTN calls.

I want to integrate conference calls in the app ,to make calls from a single client to many client or PSTN at same time.

But I couldn't find the steps.Kindly suggest the changes I need to make on my Server code and the Android code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like you are looking for the [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) noun.  If you've made a call from Client to PSTN, you've likely set up some TwiML that looks like this:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+15555556666">+15555555555</Dial>
</Response>
```

That TwiML tells Twilio to take the incoming Client call, dial the PSTN phone number and bridge those two calls together.

If you wanted to put that Client call into a conference instead you would use the  noun:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
         <Conference>MyConference</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

You could use this same TwiML with a Twilio phone number so that if someone dials into Twilio via PSTN, they would also get dropped into the same conference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you suggest the changes need to make in the server code [link](https://github.com/twilio/mobile-quickstart). I believe I have to use code `Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>(); parameters.put("To","conference:MyConferenceName");`

Comment: In the python code (server.py) if you wanted to put the incoming client call into a conference you wold change line 61 to `resp.dial(to, callerId=caller_id).conference('MyConference')`

Comment: I made the modification as suggested and modify my android code as follows.But still only a single device is connected.  `Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("To","conference:MyConference");
        if (clientDevice != null) {
        
            connection = clientDevice.connect(params, null);
        } `

Comment: How do you expect the other participants in the conference to connect to it?  Are they connecting to it via your app, or are they dialing in via PSTN?  Or do you want Twilio to call them and drop them into the conference?

Comment: I changed my server code to  `resp.dial(callerId=from_value).conference('MyConference')`
Its working now but I want Twilio to call them and drop them into the conference.

Comment: If you want Twilio to call the other participants you'll need to use the REST API in your server app to initiate an outbound call to each of those participants.  When the call is answered Twilio will make an HTTP request to your server looking for the TwiML to execute.  You can return the same Twiml already used to put the Client call into the conference.